# Divide as evenly as possible the value defined in var into the a variable length array

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to split the remainder as evenly as possible where var is not divisible into the array count.

I've tried the following, which gives me a rounded split into the array item. I'm looking for a way to identify the remainder and then split that as evenly as possible into each array index value.

```
    for n in ${!variableLengthArray[@]} ; do

        divideCount=$(( ${variableLengthArray[$n]} / $var ))

        variableLengthArray[$n]=$(echo "($divideCount+0.5)/1" | bc )

    done
```

EXAMPLE1:

Input:

```
    var=11
    variableLengthArray[0]=0
    variableLengthArray[1]=0
    variableLengthArray[2]=0
```

Ideal Output:

```
    variableLengthArray[0]=4
    variableLengthArray[1]=4
    variableLengthArray[2]=3
```

EXAMPLE2:

Input:

```
    var=33
    variableLengthArray[0]=0
    variableLengthArray[1]=0
    variableLengthArray[2]=0
    variableLengthArray[3]=0
    variableLengthArray[4]=0
    variableLengthArray[5]=0
```

Ideal Output:

```
    variableLengthArray[0]=6
    variableLengthArray[1]=6
    variableLengthArray[2]=6
    variableLengthArray[3]=5
    variableLengthArray[4]=5
    variableLengthArray[5]=5
```

Comment: I might as well be the first to say it ... What have you tried? (And as bonus, it would be great if you could define "as evenly as possible".)

Comment: some verbal description of what your "rule" is might help make this Q less ambiguous. I see 4 inputs and 3 outputs. "Evenly divided" to me, means 2 outputs. Again, 6 inputs and 6 outputs, not 3? And does the first line of input, i.e. `var=33` part of the input (but not output), or else, what does it mean in the context of your problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, please see changes and thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to divide the input by the number of output slots. The shell only does integer division, so you the result will be the number to store in each slot. The remainder of the division tells you how many slots get the result *plus one*.

As a concrete example,

```
$ var=11
$ slots=3
$ result=$((var / slots))
$ k=$((var % slots ))
$ for ((i=0; i<k; i++)); do
> variableLengthArray[i]=$(( result + 1 ))
> done
$ for ((i=k; i < slots; i++)); do
> variableLengthArray[i]=$result
> done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that indexing of your array variable starts from 0 and is contiguous the following code will do what you want:

```
n=${#variableLengthArray[@]}
ratio=$(($var / $n))
rem=$(($var % $n))
for i in ${!variableLengthArray[@]} ; do
    variableLengthArray[$i]=$(( $ratio + ($i < $rem ? 1 : 0) ))
done
```